# Curriculum Vitae in application for PhD

Tags: phd, cv

I have contacted a professor (in Europe) informally and asked for a PhD position. She answered in positive manner and asked for a CV.

What should I include?
Do people in academia care about the usual 2-page restriction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally I would say No, people do not put restrictions on CVs unless specifically asking for it.

In a case such as the one you decribe you should send a complete CV that lists everything that can be meriting for the position you will apply for. The following would be of interest:

1. A brief description of your drive and interest to pursue a PhD
2. Course work includig grades
3. Scientific/equivalent experience is a given of course.
4. Any publications and scientific/equivalent reports you have written. If you have some significant report/thesis that you have written during your education, you can list that as well. I would say that any report longer than, say, 10 pages of text might be useful to list. In such cases you should perhaps add inwhat context (Course) the text was written. In the end what a person looking for a PhD position will be looking for is someone who can successfully complete work and write it up in written form.
5. Scientific/equivalent presentations in a public context, open department seminar, scientific meeting etc.
6. Any academic work experience such as working inlabs etc.
7. General work experience. This can be listed to highlght work experience of any kind. This shows how active you are.
8. Anything else that you think will be meriting.

If you have written a paper (thesis) of some sort, provide a copy. Only one, the most important though. If you do not have one that is fine, no one would expect you to have written much.

Despite the length of the list try to make it brief and clear so that it can be assessed with ease. ry to find a good layout that make sthe structure easy to see.

Comment: The only thing I can think that's missing from Peter's list is references. If you have one or two well-placed people who are willing to give a reference for you, listing them here and providing (email) contact information would be a good idea.

Comment: @Bill Good point, I missed that. +1

Comment: Items (1) and (2) on your list are _not_ parts of an academic CV. They _accompany_ the CV as part of an application as a (1) statement of purpose or cover letter and (2) a transcript (the latter if needed), but are not normally listed in a CV. Degrees, overall averages, and honors should be mentioned, but "drive and interest" and individual courses are not part of the scope of a CV.

Comment: @aeismail You are right in that for you and me this would not be included but in the case of the OP I think it would be useful to include since we are dealing with a candidate looking for a PhD position. I know I would like that information. It also seems you picture all CVs having to sport the same content, I do not fully agree on that notion. A CV will be tailored in detail to suit transient needs.

Comment: A CV is customizable, but particularly for many countries in Europe, it does not include a "statement of purpose"! One _must_ include this, but as I said, it goes in the cover letter or a separate statement of purpose that gets submitted with the CV. A list of courses would be considered part of the "certifications" that are submitted as part of the hiring process.

Comment: A good answer but it assumes the op is in science. I would suggest a less-science-specific answer as your answer is quite generalizable (and the op does not mention being in a science-related field).

Comment: @earthling Good point.

Comment: @aeismail Good points. If I read your comment correctly does that mean that the culture in a particular country or field is so strong that any deviation from a norm is unthinkable?

Comment: It's not unthinkable, but it's definitely inadvisable. The further afield you go, the more likely you're going to have an adverse reaction on the part of someone reviewing your applications!

Comment: I would be surprised if a PhD applicant really needed a CV that was longer than 2 pages. So while not a rule, it is probably a reasonable guideline.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else had mentioned this on a related question here: the words "curriculum vitae" [are taken from the Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae) for "course of my life". So there's not much point in a page restriction :), unlike a corporate resume, which is often required to be one page or one sheet.

As for what you should put in it, Peter's answer is very comprehensive.