# What's in a 'vita'?

Tags: cv

A professor agreed to write me a letter of recommendation for a military program.  He said 'yeah, send me a vita'.  What is a vita?

Comment: I thought this was a silly question until I tried to google the (incorrect) spelling of vitae and saw all sorts of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: For your second question, yes--send him instructions (if the program provides instructions for letter writers) or a link to the program page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is simply shorthand for curriculum vitae, also called a CV or resume. He's just asking you to send him your resume so he can list stuff you've done when writing your letter.

Comment: Does he want to know just stuff I did in the university, or my career in general?

Comment: Probably both, with an emphasis on academic stuff.

Answer (score 12):

A "vita" is just a short term for a *curriculum vitae* (i.e., CV) which is similar to, but not exactly the same as, a resumé.

There are many questions on this site, like [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/curriculum-vitae-in-application-for-phd) asking about how to create a CV and many other webpages which can help with figuring out how to write one.